# Getting 'WrappedRuntimeException' when using XSL-FO in an Xpage

Tags: xslt, xpages, lotus-domino, xsl-fo

I am trying to create a PDF from the contents of an xpage.  I am following the format that Paul Calhoun used in Notes in 9 #102.   I am able to create PDF's for views, but having trouble creating one for a document.  I do not think the error is in Paul's code so I am not including it here, although I can if need be.

To generate the XML to display I use the generateXML() method of the document class in java.  I get a handle to the backend document and then return the XML.  The XML appears well formed, the top level tab is `<document>`.  I pass this XML to the transformer which is using Apache FOP.  All of my code is contained in the beforeRenderResponse of an xAgent.

The XSL stylesheet that I am using is a stripped down version to just get a proof of concept to work.  I am going to include it, because the problem likely resides with this code.  I am totally new to XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output
        method="xml"
        version="1.0"
        omit-xml-declaration="no"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param
        name="versionParam"
        select="'1.0'" />

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master
                    master-name="outpage"
                    page-height="11in"
                    page-width="8.5in"
                    margin-top="1in"
                    margin-bottom="1in"
                    margin-left="1in"
                    margin-right="1in">
                    <fo:region-body />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
                <fo:block
                        font-size="16pt"
                        font-weight="bold"
                        space-after="5mm">
                        Apache FOP Proof of Concept.
                    </fo:block>
            </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the log file I get the message:

```
FATAL ERROR:  'com.ibm.xtq.common.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: D:\Program Files\IBM\Domino\<document form='PO'>
```

The error echos the entire XML in the log that it is trying to transform and ends with:

```
 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)'
```

Notice that Domino is trying to include the XML in a path.  I know this is wrong, but don't know what to do to fix it.

EDIT: This is the Java class that runs the transformation.  This code is from Paul Calhoun's demo.

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;

public class DominoXMLFO2PDF {
    public static void getPDF(OutputStream pdfout,String xml,String xslt, Boolean authReq, String usernamepass) {
        try {
            //System.out.println("Transforming...");
            Source xmlSource,xsltSource;  //Source xmlSource = new StreamSource("http://localhost/APCC.nsf/Main?ReadViewEntries&count=999&ResortAscending=2");
            xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);  //Source xsltSource = new StreamSource("http://localhost/APCC.nsf/viewdata.xsl");
            xsltSource = new StreamSource(xslt);// configure fopFactory as desired              

            final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            // configure foUserAgent as desired

            // Setup output
            // OutputStream out = pdfout;
            // out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

            try {
                // Construct fop with desired output format
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,foUserAgent, pdfout);
                // Setup XSLT
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
                //transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "Company List"); // Set the value of a <param> in the stylesheet
                Source src = xmlSource; // Setup input for XSLT transformation
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler()); // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
                transformer.transform(src, res); // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing

            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is called in the xAgent using this line:

```
var retOutput = jce.getPDF(pageOutput, xmlsource, xsltsource, authReq, usernamepass);
```

The xmlsource is set with this line where the method returns XML using Document.generateXML():

```
var xmlsource = statusBean.generateXML(POdata, sessionScope.unidPDF);
```

Comment: Steve, check the log to see if there's a reference to "caused by" associated with the exception... if so, add that to your question, as it may provide a hint to what's going on here.

Comment: There is no reference to "caused by".  I just looked in the workspace logs as well and nothing there (as usual) just that a 'Exception processing xpage request'.   I think the exception is caused by it trying to map the XML to a path, like it was resource.

Comment: You need to carefully handle the XML and how you pass it to the function. It seems like you pass it as String to a function that assumes the string is an URL and not XML content! Provide the Java you use, so we can have a look

Comment: Stephan, you might be on to something.  In Paul's example, he passes an URL that resolves to XML, in my example I pass a String that is XML.  Let me think over this, and I will soon add the code to the original question.

Comment: Stephan, hoping you see this before your day ends.  I updated the question with the java code.  The java code expects a String, which is what I feed it, but I bet it fails when it tried to create the Stream Source.  I am rushing here because I know you are like 11hrs ahead of me :)

Comment: Stephan, I got it figured out.  If you don't mind, when you get in tomorrow go ahead and answer the question since your comment above was what clued me in on how to fix this.  I added the line: StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml) to the java transformer class, and then passed the 'reader' to the StreamSource.   This got me past that exception, and now I have a new one, but hallelujah it is a relief to see a new exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the XMLSource! When you look at Paul's code:

```
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource("http://localhost/APCC.nsf/Main?ReadViewEntries");
```

This **points to** an URL where to retrieve XML.On the other hand your code:

```
 xmlsource = statusBean.generateXML(POdata, sessionScope.unidPDF);
```

**contains** the XML. So you need to change to:

```
   String xmlstring = statusBean.generateXML(POdata, sessionScope.unidPDF);
   Source xmlsource = new StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(xmlstring));
```

I strongly suggest you try to keep all the Java in a java class, so you don't need to wrap/upwrap the objects in SSJS. Have a look at [my series on FO](http://www.wissel.net/blog/htdocs/DominoXSLT) too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this in your comment!!!  It seems so obvious now looking back at it.  I have read your entire FO series and gained much from it.  I basically started with no knowledge in this area, and you an Paul have helped tremendously.   I also did think about keeping this all in java and avoiding using the SSJS entirely.

Comment: Stephan, I don't know if you realize this, but the link for part 6 of your FO series is broken, so I guess I haven't read the 'entire' series.  Thanks again!!!